# Unable to include Objective C Categories from CoreBluetooth Framework

Tags: objective-c

Currently, I am trying to make categories of Classes from CoreBluetooth Framework, but whenever i am trying to do the following : New File-> Objective C categories -> "I get only Foundation and UIKit Framework's classes and not the other ones."

1. I have also tried adding the CoreBlueTooth Framework but there still I am not getting the classes of CoreBluetooth Framework.

Comment: Why don't you create a category for `NSObject` then change it to any other class you want? Is selecting the name and typing another one so hard?

Comment: If that is not working the You can SubClass and add your custom  members there also.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode helps you with creating Categories for Foundation Kit Framework and UIKit Framework.

For creating categories of other classes. Its the same process. New File-> Objective C categories. now in "Category on" you write your class name of the CoreBluetooth framework of which you are creating a Category.

Now, the last step would be to import the CoreBluetooth Framework in your category.
Say, CBCentralManager+MyCategory.h

```
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>
@interface MyCategory (CBCentralManager)

@end
```

Once you add it in this way, next time you create a category for classes of this framework, you will find "Category on" (in Category Creation) will help you to do it. It will provide autocompletion just like it should be.